# Uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectExpection:Failed to connect to/ 127.0.0.1:8081

Tags: react-native, expo, command-line-interface, bluestacks

"Uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectExpection:Failed to connect to/ 127.0.0.1:8081" occurs whenever i run exp://127.0.0.1:8081 in my expo app in my bluestacks app player, i need it to run my react native

i have tried reloading and its still the same thing and also restating my app

Answer (score 1):

**Check if the Metro Bundler is Running:** You can manually start it by running npm start or yarn start in your project directory.

**BlueStacks Configuration:** In BlueStacks settings, check if there are any network or proxy configurations that might be interfering with the connect

**Expo Configuration:** If you are using Expo, make sure your Expo CLI is updated and configured correctly. Sometimes running expo start --tunnel can help

Comment: Can you share which one of those was your problem and mark my answer as solution if that helped you please :)